# d3 select change node datum

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In my d3 charts, I sometimes create my nodes with a `parent.selectAll().data()`.
Then retrieve later the created node with `parent.select()` to continue changing its children. The issue I face is it seems that d3 is changing the `__data__` of the node when I select it again, it gives it the data of its parent instead of the one I assigned to it in the `selectAll` call.

I reproduce this issue in a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dgm4snau/2/

Do I do something wrong? How can I select again the created node without overriding its `__data__`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making a subselection with `.select()` has [a side effect](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#select):

> If the current element has associated data, this data is inherited by the returned subselection, and automatically bound to the newly selected elements.

This is what you're seeing, and happens by design. The solution in your case is to use `.selectAll()` instead of `.select()` for the subselection:

```
level2Elem = level2Holder.selectAll('.level2');
```

Modified fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dgm4snau/3/).